# Marshmallow permission : Component Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Looking into marshmallow permission modal, it calls `onRequestPermissionsResult()` before `onResume()` of Activity or Fragment.

### Problem statement :

If we have any action performed on Action result (i.e. permission allowed), like I want to remove current fragment, then it is not possible because fragment and container activity both are into pause state. So is there any way to call `onResume()` before `onRequestPermissionsResult()` ?

### Solution, I am using

I am using flags for permission, which is being reset on `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and being verified on `onResume()`. But this seems a confusing way in my case.

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to change the order implemented those callbacks but you can easily hack-around it. I'll show two different ways:

Simply post:

```
private static final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if(... condition ...)
        uiHandler.post(onPermission_condition);
}

private Runnable onPermission_condition = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ... do stuff here
    }
}
```

}

Use a flag:

```
private boolean shouldDoStuff = false;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if(... condition ...)
        shouldDoStuff = true;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  if(shouldDoStuff) {
     shouldDoStuff = false;
     ... do stuff here  
  }
}
```

Comment: flag solution will create some confusion in my case. But handler solution I never tried. so I am going to try it and will update you. thank you for the valuable answer.

Comment: I don't think Handler solution is a good one.  It just takes more time to complete so your 'onResume()' might still be called after 'onRequestPermissionsResult' but with less probability.

I think using flag is still better, because it's correct. (But very ugly)

I still don't know better solution.